# How to create the last horizontal line of a table to be bigger in length?

Tags: tables, line

I have the following code:

`\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{c c c c c}
\caption{\textit{D-optimal ΒΑ(12, 5, 3, 2)}} \\ 
\hline
1 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 1 \\
2 & 2 & 2 & 3 & 1 \\
3 & 3 & 3 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 2 \\
1 & 3 & 3 & 3 & 2 \\
2 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 2 \\
2 & 2 & 3 & 2 & 2 \\
3 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 \\
3 & 3 & 1 & 3 & 2 \\
1 & 2 & 1 & 1 & 3 \\
2 & 3 & 2 & 2 & 3 \\
3 & 1 & 3 & 3 & 3 \\
\hline
\end{longtable}
\end{document}`

How can I make the `\hline` directives at the start and at the end of the table to be bigger in length?

I have tried by using `\hlinefill`or `\hfill`, but it does not work. Thank you.

Comment: I would expect the underline in the caption to be shorter not longer than the hline? (of course you have not provided an example so it is impossible to see. If you fixed your example so it showed the issue, we could test...

Comment: What's with the `[-2ex]` and `[-4ex]` vertical spacing adjustments? If normal linespacing rules are in effect, these spacing adjustments make for extremely ugly and illegible output. Please tell us more about your document setup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first line, i.e., the one associated with the caption text, is longer than the `\hline` at the bottom of the `longtable` environment simply because the first line is part of the caption, *not* part of the tabular-like material. This may be verified by adding an `\hline` directive immediately after the `\caption` directive.

You really ought to reconsider the wisdom of using underlining for the purpose of emphasizing material in a typeset document. In particular, since you're already using italics to highlight the caption material, are you actually concerned that your readers will not be able to figure out what's the caption of the table, and what's the body of the table?

A full MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{c c c c c}
% aside: do you really need to underline the caption text?
\caption{\underline{\textit{D-optimal ΒΑ(12, 5, 3, 2)}}} \\ 
\hline % <--- new,  just to illustrate width of tabular-like material
1 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 1 \\
2 & 2 & 2 & 3 & 1 \\
3 & 3 & 3 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 2 \\
1 & 3 & 3 & 3 & 2 \\
2 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 2 \\
2 & 2 & 3 & 2 & 2 \\
3 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 \\
3 & 3 & 1 & 3 & 2 \\
1 & 2 & 1 & 1 & 3 \\
2 & 3 & 2 & 2 & 3 \\
3 & 1 & 3 & 3 & 3 \\
\hline
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum to address the OP's follow-up question*: If you want to delimit the tabular-like material with full-width lines ("rules" in typographic jargon), irrespective of the width of the tabular material, you shouldn't be using `\hline` to begin with. Instead, use `\hrule` directives before and after the `tabular` environment, as is demonstrated in the following code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption} % for \captionof macro
\begin{document}
\captionof{table}{\textit{D-optimal ΒΑ(12, 5, 3, 2)}}
\hrule % full-width rule
\begingroup\centering % optional -- center-set the "tabular" env.
\begin{tabular}{ccccc}
1 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 1 \\
2 & 2 & 2 & 3 & 1 \\
3 & 3 & 3 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 2 \\
1 & 3 & 3 & 3 & 2 \\
2 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 2 \\
2 & 2 & 3 & 2 & 2 \\
3 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 \\
3 & 3 & 1 & 3 & 2 \\
1 & 2 & 1 & 1 & 3 \\
2 & 3 & 2 & 2 & 3 \\
3 & 1 & 3 & 3 & 3 \\
\end{tabular}\par
\endgroup % end of scope of "\centering" directive
\hrule % another full-width rule
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But how can I make the \hline (both of them) to fill all the line of the document?

Comment: @VassilisChasiotis - There is only one `\hline` directive in your code. (My code has two `\hline` directives, and they have the exact same widths.) Hence, what do you mean by "both of them"? Please clarify. Incidentally, I already gave my opinion: You should *not* underline the caption.

Comment: I will not underline the caption. I am talking about your code, so for the two `\hline` you have, how can I make them  to fill both lines of the document?

Comment: @VassilisChasiotis - The two `\hline` directives in my code have the exact same lengths. Is that not what you're getting as well? Please advise.

Comment: Yes I am getting the same lengths for both of the two `\hline` directives. How can I make now the lengths for both of the two `\hline` directives to be bigger? That is, I want the lines that created by the two `\hline` directives to complete the whole lines and not just a part of them.

Comment: @VassilisChasiotis - The lengths of the `\hline` rules are determined by the widths of tabular-like material the rules are associated with. If you want the rules to be as wide as `\textwidth`, you shouldn't be using `\hline`. Instead, you should be using `\hrule` directives, *outside of* the tabular-like environments. I'll post an addendum to show how this might be done.